# Cannot pass null argument when using type hinting

Tags: php, type-hinting

The following code:

```php
class Type {

}

function foo(Type $t) {

}

foo(null);
```

failed at run time:

> PHP Fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to foo() must not be null

Why is it not allowed to pass null just like other languages?

Answer (score 462, accepted):

**PHP 7.1 or newer** (released 2nd December 2016)

You can explicitly declare a variable to be `null` with this syntax

```
function foo(?Type $t) {
}
```

this will result in

```
$this->foo(new Type()); // ok
$this->foo(null); // ok
$this->foo(); // error
```

So, if you want an optional argument you can follow the convention `Type $t = null` whereas if you need to make an argument accept both `null` and its type, you can follow above example.

You can [read more](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types).

---

**PHP 7.0 or older**

You have to add a default value like

```
function foo(Type $t = null) {

}
```

That way, you can pass it a null value.

This is documented in the section in the manual about [Type Declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration):

> The declaration can be made to accept `NULL` values if the default value of the parameter is set to `NULL`.

Comment: So why isn't null the *null object*?

Comment: Most languages allow null to have any type. In this scenario.

Comment: In my opinion this is a poor language construct. 1. In other languages null has the ability to be of any type thus making null a valid argument in this case. 2: Php is using a default value for an argument to specify that null is allowable, this is obscure and it makes a mandatory parameter impossible even if the developer wants to force a null to be explicitly passed.

Comment: I agree with @Henry, in addition it looks weird to have required params after what looks like an optional param.

Comment: I agree with @Henry only on 2. Regarding 1 the fact that you can't pass null to `function foo(Type $t)` is a VERY good thing; see [Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type#cite_note-4)

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu If you say that 1 is a very good thing, wouldn't that make 2 a "extremely good thing"? I mean, you have to declare explicitly where you want a null value, thus avoiding null surprises. Then why is that a bad thing?

Comment: @RobertoMaldonado As of PHP 7.1 you can put `?T` as a type hint so his 2nd point is not 100% valid any more.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Oh right. I god messed up lol. I thought you were refering to OP points instead of Henry's. Still, in summary, explicitly declaring a null-accepting variable should be a good thing too IMO.

Comment: @RobertoMaldonado yes, for example, when the business rules demand it

Comment: @RobertoMaldonado the main idea is that it is explicit; before `PHP 7.1` one must also set a `default null` when he wants only the possibility of receiving a null value

Answer (score 40):

Starting from PHP 7.1, [**nullable types**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) are available, as both function return types and parameters. The type `?T` can have values of the specified Type `T`, or `null`.

So, your function could look like this:

```
function foo(?Type $t)
{

}
```

As soon as you can work with PHP 7.1, this notation should be preferred over `function foo(Type $t = null)`, because it still forces the caller to explicitly specify an argument for the parameter `$t`.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
function foo(Type $t = null) {

}
```

Check out [PHP function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Comment: The problem I have with this is that it changes the definition of the function. Now the parameter is optional - which isn't really what the author intended (although, if he is passing it null, it is implicitly optional).

Answer (score 12):

**As of PHP 8.0** (released November 26, 2020), you can also use the [**nullable union types**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.union.nullable).

This means that you are allowed to pass either `Type` or `null` as the parameter value:

```
class Type {}
function foo(Type|null $param) {
    var_dump($param);
}

foo(new Type()); // ok : object(Type)#1
foo(null);       // ok : NULL
```

Read more about [union types](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#union-types).

Answer (score 6):

As other answers already mentioned, this is only possible if you specify `null` as the default value.

But the cleanest type-safe object oriented solution would be a [NullObject](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NullObject):

```
interface FooInterface
{
    function bar();
}
class Foo implements FooInterface
{
    public function bar()
    {
        return 'i am an object';
    }
}
class NullFoo implements FooInterface
{
    public function bar()
    {
        return 'i am null (but you still can use my interface)';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
function bar_my_foo(FooInterface $foo)
{
    if ($foo instanceof NullFoo) {
        // special handling of null values may go here
    }
    echo $foo->bar();
}

bar_my_foo(new NullFoo);
```

Comment: This approach is often impractical, because instead of 1 class, you now need 3. Also, it forces the writer of `NullFoo` to override abstract methods, even though they have no meaning (by definition of `null`).

Comment: In my experience the NullObject pattern can be practical, if you work in general in a very strict, classical OO way. In the answer, imo the NullObject pattern is a bit abused, as it is especially meant to avoid `if (something is null)` checks, as the NullObject is meant to cover all behavior of a non-existing value and any outside collaborator should not need to be interested in whether an object is non-existing (null) or not.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was the native "trim" function, that not accepts null.
Let's suppose that you've this code:

```
if (trim($tables) != '') 
{
 //code 
}
```

PHP8 will throws you this error; so you if you're working on a legacy code, I suggest you to create a custom "trim" function, like this one, to make it work quickly.

```
  public function custom_trim(?string $value)
  {
    return trim($value ?? '') ;
  }
```

I really hate this change from 7.4 to 8