# Edit entity field to null using Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I got an error when editing Entity field to NULL if this field had value before. For first time persisting to database, I can submit it with NULL value. This error occured when change the value back to NULL :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Sifo\SharedBundle\Entity\BlogMenu::setBlogPage() must be an instance
>   of Sifo\SharedBundle\Entity\BlogPage, null given, called in
>   C:\Sifony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php
>   on line 438 and defined in
>   C:\Sifony\src\Sifo\SharedBundle\Entity\BlogMenu.php line 332

This is my entity BlogMenu.php Line 332 :

```
// ...

 * Set blogPage
 *
 * @param \Sifo\SharedBundle\Entity\BlogPage $blogPage
 * @return blogPage
 */
public function setBlogPage(\Sifo\SharedBundle\Entity\BlogPage $blogPage) // Line 332
{
    $this->blogPage = $blogPage;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get blogPage
 *
 * @return \Sifo\SharedBundle\Entity\BlogPage 
 */
public function getBlogPage()
{
    return $this->blogPage;
}

// ...
```

updateAction in my controller is like this :

```
/**
 * Edits an existing BlogMenu entity.
 *
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('SifoSharedBundle:BlogMenu')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find BlogMenu entity.');
    }

    $entity->setOperator($user->getName());
    $form = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_blog_menu_show', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('SifoAdminBundle:edit:layout.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
        'user'   => $user,
    ));
}
```

This is my FormType :

```
<?php

// ...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('blog_page', 'entity', array(
                'required' => false, 
                'empty_value' => 'admin.choice.choosePage',
                'class' => 'Sifo\SharedBundle\Entity\BlogPage'))

// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to this

```
public function setBlogPage(\Sifo\SharedBundle\Entity\BlogPage $blogPage = null) 
{
    $this->blogPage = $blogPage;

    return $this;
}
```

As I told you in comment, this is due to [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). Type hinting is used to check type (classes; not primitive type, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584145/php-cannot-pass-null-argument-when-using-type-hinting/14584208#14584208)) of arguments passed to a function. If you want to let your function accept `null` type you should specify it.

Is better to use type hinting as it is "safer" and will not cause "side effects" (if possible). Let's think about a third party library or vendor: if you use a function from a third party library you should know the parameter types and if you attempt to pass the wrong type, the "compiler" (parser) will notify you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good way to solve this problem. I removed the variable declaration as entity in my Entity.

```
 * Set blogPage
 *
 * @param \Sifo\SharedBundle\Entity\BlogPage $blogPage
 * @return blogPage
 */
public function setBlogPage($blogPage) // Line 332
{
    $this->blogPage = $blogPage;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This will resolve the problem but it's not type safe

Comment: @DonCallisto : can you suggest a safe way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case prblem was in `php.ini` `max_input_vars` variable. It was `1000` by default but I sent 3k+
Both ideas are bad: allow null and remove declaration