# Edit parent variable

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

So I'm trying to edit the property `category` from the child class, but for some reasons I'm getting back an error. This I know why because there needs to be 2 arguments, but one is allready set in de parent class.

Code:

The Child

```
class RestaurantController extends CompanyController
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(null, "restaurant");
        //$this->category = "restaurant";
    }
    public function getCompany($slug){
        $company = parent::index($slug);
        return view("restaurant.profile")->withInformation($company);
    }
}
```

The Parent

```
class CompanyController extends Controller 
{
    protected $company;
    public $category;

    public function __construct(CompanyRepository $company, $category = '')
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    public function index($slug)
    {
        $company = $this->company->getCompany($this->category, $slug);

        return compact('company');
    }
}
```

Now I need to know how to work a way around it.

**Edit1**

The error I'm getting

Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController::__construct() must be an instance of App\Repositories\CompanyRepository, null given, called in /var/www/atify.info/dev-system/app/Http/Controllers/RestaurantController.php on line 16

**edit2**

This Child

```
class RestaurantController extends CompanyController
{
    public function getCompany($slug){
        $company = parent::index($slug);
        return view("restaurant.profile")->withInformation($company);
    }
}
```

The Parent

```
use App\Repositories\CompanyRepository;
class CompanyController extends Controller 
{
    protected $company;

    public function __construct(CompanyRepository $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    public function index($slug)
    {
        $company = $this->company->getCompany($slug);

        return compact('company');
    }
}
```

So then I needed a category (for extra check. Otherwise you could retrieve the company inside another child with wrong functions) because I have many childs and each child have special functions

Comment: Please include the error you're getting.

Comment: @jfadich Edited!

Comment: You're passing a `null` as the first argument to `parent::__construct(null, "restaurant");` but the parent method requires you to pass a `CompanyRepository` object as the first argument.... you need to intantiate a `CompanyRepository` object to pass instead of that null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584145/cannot-pass-null-argument-when-using-type-hinting

Comment: @MarkBaker True I know that null breaks, but the `CompanyRepository` is set in the `CompanyController`. Isn't there some kind of thing that will ignore the first argument. Somthing like a default?

Comment: "but the CompanyRepository is set in the CompanyController" - no it's not. If you don't pass a value for the company to the constructor the company will not be set.

Comment: @dan08 Well before I added the `category` it worked even without setting the `CompanyRepository` in the child. Well maybe it's not set but it's called so I don't have to call it over and over again in the `CompanyController`

Comment: So what did the parent class look like before you added category? How was it called?

Comment: @MarkBaker Updated

Comment: So even the original would only have worked if a CompanyRepository was passed to the constructor when it was instantiated

Comment: True, but what i wanted to know was is there a workaround for it so i don't have to pass it everytime through the constructor of the child and i don't want to call it everytime inside the `CompanyController` thats why the `$this->company` and there isn't another way to assign this to the property right or is there?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you would want for the child class:

```
class RestaurantController extends CompanyController
{
    public $category = 'restuarant';

    public function __construct(CompanyRepository $company){
        parent::__construct($company, $this->category);
    }

    public function getCompany($slug){
        $company = parent::index($slug);
        return view("restaurant.profile")->withInformation($company);
    }
}
```

If this is all you are doing in the constructor you can eliminate the child constructor and change the parent constructor like so.

```
 public function __construct(CompanyRepository $company, $category = null)
    {
      if( $category ){
        $this->category = $category;
      }
      $this->company = $company;
    }
```

Then every child class just set the category attribute

```
class ChildController extends CompanyController
{
    public $category = 'Child';
}
```

Comment: Well that works! But now everytime I call extend the `CompanyController` I have to add this in the constructor right?

Comment: Not really, you could just set the category and handle it in the parent constructor (i'll update the answer)