# Giving a default object to my class method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, default-parameters

I want to pass a `DateTimeZone` object to my method in my class `Test`. I have the following code:

```
class Test {
    function __construct( $timezone_object = new DateTimeZone() ) {
        // Do something with the object passed in my function here
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the above doesn't work. It gave me an error. I know I can do the following instead:

```
class Test {
    function __construct( $timezone_object = NULL ) {
        if ( $timezone_object == NULL)
            $to_be_processed = new DateTimeZone(); // Do something with my variable here
        else 
            $to_be_processed = new DateTimeZone( $timezone_object ); // Do something with the variable here if this one is executed, note that $timezone_object has to be the supported timezone format provided in PHP Manual
    }
}
```

However, I think that the second choice seems rather unclean. Is there a way to declare my method like the first choice?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - that won't work because type hinting will throw an exception if a null is passed in. You could do \DateTimeZone $timezone_object = null - giving it a null default will allow it, but the solution doesn't really help him.

Comment: It's not possible to create objects as part of the function definition.  Your only allowed to use things that are treated as constants (or things you can use as a constant) at compile time (when the definitions are parsed and complied by the PHP thingy jiggy)  {can't spell interpreter}

Comment: Basically at the time the functions and methods are parsed PHP is not aware of all the classes, so it simply can't use them.  Or something along those lines, I am sure there are more "Technical" explanations for this, but that's the basic gist of it.  As other noted the preferred way is to type hint the argument set it to null by default and check within the method and set it there.  Or just not set a default value and always pass it one.  Personally I would do #2

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - I'm just going by the code he put in the question - he specifically checks null. Therefore, it would appear to be a use case. If he passes something else, he should be wrapping this in a try/catch block and looking for that. It's not the classes responsibility to handle this, it's the calling code's responsibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for succinct code, you could do

```
class Test {
    function __construct( \DateTimeZone $timezone_object = null ) {
        $this->ts = $timezone_object ?? new DateTimeZone();
    }
}
```

the double ?? is an if null check. So you have the type hinting which will only allow DateTimeZone or Null value in (so that's safe), then you just assign a new DateTimeZone instance if the argument was null, otherwise, use the passed in value.

Edit: Found info on default null for PHP 7.1+

[Cannot pass null argument when using type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584145/cannot-pass-null-argument-when-using-type-hinting)

So the code could be even more esoteric, with slightly less key strokes

```
class Test {
    function __construct( ?\DateTimeZone $timezone_object ) {
        $this->ts = $timezone_object ?? new DateTimeZone();
    }
}
```

But in my opinion, this is just horrible.

Comment: Oh one more thing, why is the second one horrible in your opinion? Is it because it's less readable?

Comment: @RichardW - in my experience, sometimes less is not more. The ?? is bad enough, let alone requiring the knowledge to know that ? before a type hint means you allow nulls. Code in my opinion should be instantly intuitive to the reader. If you didn't know what ?\DateTimeZone does, you would need to spend 10-15mins getting your google search right to figure it out. Is that "?" worth $20 for every developer that looks at it that doesn't know the syntax? Time = Money

Comment: I see, thank you for sharing your experience. Anecdotal notes like these certainly help me to become a better coder.