# What does typehint ?string mean

Tags: php, class, types

I read this [article](https://stitcher.io/blog/typed-properties-in-php-74) and was confused about this code `public ?string $b = 'foo';`

As far as I understand `$b` is a string variable.
Is the `?` before `string` intended to mention that this variable is also nullable?
If so than it is the same as
`public string | null $b = 'foo';` which is in my option much intutive to understand.

Comment: The possible duplicate does not mention the possible alternative notation with union types. In my eyes this is no duplicate.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450841

Comment: See also [PHP union types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66403166/9193372).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP 7.1 nullable return types or nullable type hinting with a question mark exists. Since PHP 8.0 union types are available. If you want to write `null|string` you can do this since PHP 8.0. This notation expresses the same as `?string`.

Which notation you use is up to your personal taste. Since the notation with the question mark is shorter, I personally would prefer this notation.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out.